# Regex Pattern for extracting a comma separated number while ignoring dates

Tags: regex, date, numbers, csv

I've not been using regex very long, and I'm struggling with defining the right regex pattern.  I've searched this site and many others not quite finding what I need.

Here's the sub-string from a file I need to parse:

```
    As of 10 AM on:
    9/7/2012         227,134 mmcf.
    9/9/2011         1,224,376 mmcf.
    9/10/2010        424 mmcf.
```

What I need to extract is any number that is not a date from a line(s) inside the file. Each of the lines in the example above are newlines in the file, with the date being the first word in the line (as you'd probably expect).  The whitespace following the date is actually two tabs and a single space.  I need to extract the value **227,134** only, and I need to be able to grab that value for any number 1 - 999,999,999.  As you can see, the commas are included in the value.

I've been able to create a pattern that matches any of the values (123,456; 123,224,376; and 424), but it also matches each of the date properties (month, day, year).  I have a pattern that grabs the date & white space, but I'm not sure how to grab the value after that.

Here is the current pattern I am using:

```
    ^(?:3[01]|[12][0-9]|[1-9])[/.-](?:1[0-2]|[1-9])[/.-][0-9]{4}         [,0-9]+\b
```

This matches the following:

```
    9/7/2012         227,134
    9/9/2011         1,224,376
    9/10/2010        424
```

Is there a way to match part of a pattern and exclude it from the remainder of the pattern?

What is the best approach for this?

I'm really only concerned with finding the first value (in this case, **227,134**) in the list.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
[\d\,]+(?=\smmcf\.)
```

One or more digits or commas, followed by a space and "mmcf."

Comment: This is matching part of the year, as well as the 10 in the first line

Comment: Shouldn't be. What part of the year is it matching? And did you see my last edit to account for the 10?

Comment: @CaffGeek oh, I see. Hang on.

Comment: Thanks, Phillip and CaffGeek! The updated pattern works perfectly.  If I understand this correctly, the portion of the pattern that follows the digits or commas is a positive look-ahead, correct? I presume that means a look-ahead or a look-behind is used to match but not included in the match (clearly in this example)?  Just trying to understand...

Thanks again for your help (both of you!).

Comment: @joel yup, pretty much. A positive lookahead is *non-consuming*, so it doesn't match anything and doesn't change the current position of the search, but it serves to make sure something is there.

Answer (score 0):

How about this regex?

```
^\s*\d{0,2}/\d{0,2}/\d{0,4}\s+([\d,]+)\s*.*$
```

the group is the number you want.

What this does is

- `^` start of line
- `\s*` whitespace (0 or more times)

Now get the date

- `\d{0,2}` 0-2 digits
- `/` slash
- `\d{0,2}` 0-2 digits
- `/` slash
- `\d{0,2}` 0-4 digits

Some whitespace

- `\s+` whitespace (1 or more times)

The number we want

- `([\d,]+)` capture digits and commas

And the rest of the line

- `\s*` whitespace (0 or more times)
- `.*` any more digits
- `$` end of line

Answer (score 0):

Easiest thing to do would be to match the numbers after the whitespace on the line.  You don't even need to match the dates.

```
^\s*\S+\s+([\d,]+)
```

The group will contain the number with commas still in it.

Comment: The lines actually start with whitespace, so this doesn't match

Comment: I didn't realize the lines start with a whitespace, updated my answer.